# Как передать значение поля формы в CMS Santafox?

Tags: cms

Есть сайт, использующий CMS Santafox.

Нужно внести правки в форму заказа - добавить одно поле.

Для отправки формы в cms есть шаблон, в котором поля указаны в виде `%name_value%`. Думал в динамике генерируется, но, нет.

Кто сталкивался с этой cms, подскажите где определить новое поле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел в настройках:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Немного нелогичная настройка